# Sublime Text 2 - Changing the icon on Windows

Tags: icons, sublimetext2

As the title says, how do you change Sublime Text 2 default icon on Windows(7 or 8)?

I've searched everywhere. I found the post by Jeffrey Way on Nettuts that explains how to change it on the Mac and it was as simple as putting the 'nameoftheicon.icns' file somewhere in the default folder.

Now I have two problems:

1) I can't find the folder where the icns file should be put in
2) on Git(or somewhere else) when I find the repo of an icon the things to do in order to change it, even on the Mac, are way longer than Jeff's post

I wish the Windows folder was specified in that post to but it isn't(as you know he works on Mac).

So basically **what's the fastest way** to change the icon, maybe just by putting the icns files somewhere and **avoiding the download of external software**(as some Git repos suggests)?

Comment: you can create an shortcut to sublime.exe and then in the properties panel you can easily change the shortcut icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way of changing the icon on Windows without editing either the `sublime_text.exe` file or one of the libraries with an external program. It's just one of the many, many differences between Windows and Mac. `.icns` files are specific for the Mac platform, and don't exist in the Windows versions of Sublime Text.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there a way to edit the icon without working with external software? I've formatted my computer one week ago and I don't like to install software I use once to delete it right after.

Also, if the Dribbble icon I downloaded comes in the .icns format will that somehow work on Windows or I need to manually convert it?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no easy/fast method** to change an application icon once its been compiled, however you can use a tool like [Resource Tuner](http://www.restuner.com/download.htm) to alter the resources embedded within it.

Its worth noting that if you do use Resource Tuner it only supports 32bit binaries which means you will need to modify the 32bit version of Sublime. You can adjust the four icons defined there (16,32,48 256), you will need to create your own individual ICO files for each 32bit resource, import them using resource tuner and then save our .exe

An altered 32bit version of the .exe and .ico resources are here : https://copy.com/S7kKk6rh2Q3P12iu (nothing malicious however use at your own risk)

Comment: I use  Resource Tuner to change the icon... now its bad looking LOL.

Answer (score 0):

suggest https://github.com/dbmzzo/Sublime-Text-2-Icon
may help. BTW, it provide solution of changing icon in Win\Ubuntu\Mac